# Data not showing up in DataGridView after a search query

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Hello i am trying to search for data from a table using a funcion, however when i Input the number of the customerID it doesnt show up in the data gridview but the data is still passed to my textboxes. Could anyone help me in explaining what I did wrong?

```
 Private Function SearchData(Fname As String, ID As Int32) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim newds As New DataSet
    Dim ssql As String = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE fname LIKE @Fname OR CustomerID =@ID"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr),
             cmd As New SQLiteCommand(ssql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", DbType.String).Value = Fname
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(newds, "customers")
        dt = newds.Tables(0)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ToTextbox(dt)
        End If
        dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
  Private Sub IbtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnSearch.Click

    If txtSearchName.Text <> "" Then
        SearchData(txtSearchName.Text, "0")
        Dim dt = GetSearchResults(txtSearchName.Text)
        dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = dt

    ElseIf txtSearchID.Text <> "" Then
        SearchData("0", txtSearchID.Text)
        Dim dt = GetSearchResults(txtSearchID.Text)
        dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = dt
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` before anything else. -- `SearchData()` returns a DataTable (btw, you don't need a DataSet there and you should not set the DataSource of a DataGridView there. Also remove `con.Close()`, you have an `Using` block for that) but you discard it. Then call `GetSearchResults()` which is not defined here. Why? `ToTextbox()` is also undefined. You have probably redundant method calls that overlap and you have to refine the `SELECT` query (but `Option Strict On` first, otherwise whatever you try to do to fix this is useless).

Comment: What SQLite library are you using?

Comment: Do not use dt.Load as well as da.Fill - only one is required, otherwise you're querying your database twice

Comment: White space may help in setting off different sections of code, but too much white space just makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to think about what each line of code is doing. See in line comments

```
Private Function SearchData(Fname As String, ID As Int32) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'Delete this line - there is no need for a Dataset
    Dim newds As New DataSet
    Dim ssql As String = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE fname LIKE @Fname OR CustomerID =@ID"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr),
         cmd As New SQLiteCommand(ssql, con)
        con.Open() 'Move this line - don't open the connection until directly before the .Execute...
        'The Like operator would expect a pattern to match
        'The interpolated string with the percent signs add wildcard characters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", DbType.String).Value = $"%{Fname}%"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        'Delete - We don't need a DataAdapter
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        'Delete - We already have a filled DataTable
        da.Fill(newds, "customers")
        'Delete - same as above
        dt = newds.Tables(0)
        'Delete - Have no idea what this does. You are already going to display your data in a grid
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ToTextbox(dt)
        End If
        'Delete - You will set the DataSource in the User Interface code
        dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = dt
        'Delete - End Using closes the connection and disposes the connection and command.
        con.Close()
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

The corrected code will look like this.

```
Private Function SearchData(Fname As String, ID As Int32) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ssql As String = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE fname LIKE @Fname OR CustomerID =@ID"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr),
         cmd As New SQLiteCommand(ssql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", DbType.String).Value = $"%{Fname}%"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

In the user interface code I have added in line comments.

```
Private Sub IbtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnSearch.Click
    'Declare the DataTable outside the If block
    'We do not need a New DataTable because SearchData is returning a DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable
    If txtSearchName.Text <> "" Then
        'Call only one function to return the DataTable
        'SearchData is expecting 2 parameters, a String and an Integer
        'Putting 0 in quotes makes it a String
        dt = SearchData(txtSearchName.Text, 0)
        'I removed the DataSource, Don't repeat yourself
        'Assign it once after the If
    ElseIf txtSearchID.Text <> "" Then
        'The second argument must be an Integer, therefore the CInt()
        dt = SearchData("", CInt(txtSearchID.Text))
    Else
        'Needed to add an Else to assign a value to dt if all else fails
        dt = Nothing
    End If
    dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```